# change bold to normal font when click item in listvew

Tags: android, listview, text

when click user a item in list view change text from bold to normal
my adapter :

```
    @Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
     final ViewHolder holder;

    if (row == null) {
        row = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listarticleitem, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.imageTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    holder.imageTitle.setText("Item 1");
    if(contents.get(position).getfav().equals("0"))
    {
        holder.imageTitle.setTypeface(face, Typeface.BOLD); 
    }
    else
    {
        holder.imageTitle.setTypeface(face);    
    }
    holder.imageTitle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            holder.imageTitle.setTypeface(face, Typeface.NORMAL);
        }
      });
    return row;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView imageTitle;
}
```

but not working how to solve it?
my code not work for change text to normal.
tnx

Answer (score 0):

Use `onClick` `View v` parameter for changing typeface of selected row as:

```
 @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            v.setTypeface(face, Typeface.NORMAL);
        }
```

Comment: Did you ever get a solution for this?  I just ran into this same problem myself; I can change from normal->bold just fine, but bold->normal isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, and found that Typeface.NORMAL don't work,
I change it to this and it work's:

```
setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT)
```